# Infer union of objects in TypeScript switch statement using lowercased discriminator key

Tags: typescript

How to infer the union of objects using a discriminator key converted to lowercase in a switch statement?

I'm trying to infer the specific type within the Option union based on the value of the name property. However, I'm encountering TypeScript errors because the discriminator key name is in uppercase and the comparison is case-sensitive. I have attempted two approaches to solve this. However, this approaches doesn't work as expected, and TypeScript still raises errors.

Example:

```
const toLowerCase = <T extends string>(x: T) => x.toLowerCase() as Lowercase<T>;

type Option = {
    name: "a";
    foo: "foo"
} | {
    name: "b";
    bar: "bar"
}

function printOption(option: Option) {
    switch (option.name) {
        case "a":
            console.log(option.foo)
            break
        case "b":
            console.log(option.bar)
            break
    }
}

function printOptionToLowerCase(option: Option) {
    switch (toLowerCase(option.name)) {
        case "a":
            // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Option'.
            // Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ name: "b"; bar: "bar"; }'.(2339)
            console.log(option.foo)
            break
        case "b":
            // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Option'.
            // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ name: "a"; foo: "foo"; }'.(2339)
            console.log(option.bar)
            break
    }
}

function printOptionAsserObjectField(option: Option) {
    switch (option.name.toLowerCase() as Option["name"]) {
        case "a":
            // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Option'.
            // Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ name: "b"; bar: "bar"; }'.(2339)
            console.log(option.foo)
            break
        case "b":
            // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Option'.
            // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ name: "a"; foo: "foo"; }'.(2339)
            console.log(option.bar)
            break
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0&pretty=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIBkQHcCmAnAwgQwqmAvDADwAqMqAHlKmACYQzToCWYA5gHwAUlAXDFIBKQpxiUAdPCRosuVNxG4YMjMHllOAbgBQOqAE8ADvgDyRqC3CEYAbx0xHMMNgC2qAQCJsn3U5gAZiAgXkEgnjoAvjAAPnYOTi7uXgBGvgmOKdjoqdkRkXoBAK5gwJbWRqxgUOblYNwgFlZgArXNIvb+EMgsUMAAFjANTeASSagdGf4w6ngw3p58U9NOoJAgADaoEhsg7MN1EmFCyyswKeio2ADWp46z+J5pS2fTaxCb27v7jYdZ6CdXv4Lldbv4CgUdMVSnUYJU2DURmBSIgUBgcHgDs1WkjJl0en1BtxpGi5Jjfs0xm4Jnizg95j4XkD7uAPlsdnssaNjndpiCbrz6U9Frz-O9PhyfkiJP9AczzpcBeCooUSmVmnCqoi6gBBCB4dCmFIAK1QZQAYixUBs6FyWjA2uBaY5ur0BkMKaNxlJUbIMQolIxHWAANqecaeAC6zre8gZIvlM1ZEu+dqOwTlzP5YLpceFTOZ4vZqc9YBl2UzQOzUwhOiAA)

Comment: Typescript won't be able to infer and narrow the option, since in the first case there is no relation between the return value of `toLowerCase` and the `option`. In the second case, the same thing happens, you return a new string that has no relation with the `option`. I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLXXvm), though I'm not sure if it works for you. If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Great! Thank you for your response! The solution you provided works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, will write the answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your cases, you use a function/method that returns a string, which has no relation with the `option`, thus the compiler can't narrow the type.

Not the best solution, but the simplest one is to directly mutate the `option` by converting its' name to lowercase:

```
function printOptionToLowerCase(option: Option) {
  option.name = toLowerCase(option.name)
  
  switch (option.name) {
    case 'a':
      console.log(option.foo); // no error
      break;
    case 'b':
      console.log(option.bar); // no error
      break;
  }
}
```

This way you are not creating a separate value/variable and just directly working with the `option`, which allows the compiler to infer the correct type

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIBkQHcCmAnAwgQwqmAvDADwAqMqAHlKmACYQzToCWYA5gHwAUlAXDFIBKQpxiUAdPCRosuVNxG4YMjMHllOAbgBQOqAE8ADvgDyRqC3CEdMGAB8YAb1t23YbAFtUAgOTZfXTc3ADMQED8wkEDXOwBfV0cXYLsPbz8AIxiUmAzsdEz87Lc43R0QgFcwYEtrI1YwKHNasFJEFAwcPG4QCyswAWb+kWSYXpaJNPwiaQ65bvH+ya9UIVdXCGQWKGAACxgevvBl7xHYmHU8GH9fPnO7UEgQABtUCWeQdkOJqKEglIy6FQ2AA1v8HvJrlk7jlHhAXm8Pl9Fsc8ug-vdckDQf8EgkgA)